# Family visit rejected!

Tags: visa-refusals, family

Long story short, I am a 24 years old student. I was refused a Schengen visa several times to Germany, for the reason that my intention to leave the Schengen area ........... you know how it goes.

But the problem is that my whole family is German except my mother and I; I have 3 siblings and my father who holds a German citizenship (my mother holds a residence permit) and they all live in Germany, except me. I live in Algeria for studying.

My question is: could hiring a lawyer will help get me a visa for a short visit to Germany, because I think it's a kind of serious act if I am not granted a visa for visiting my whole family. If yes, which kind of a lawyer should I hire and  which one would help me the most in my case.

Comment: Depending on the nature of your studies in Algeria, you might be considered as a dependent of your father if you are ["systematically preparing for a future profession".](http://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/the-definition-of-a-family-member-of-a-citizen-of-the-european-union-iceland-norway-liechtenstein-and-switzerland.aspx)  This could make you eligible for a [EU family member's residence card.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_card_of_a_family_member_of_a_Union_citizen)  I am **not** an expert in this area, though, so if someone else comments & says I'm full of it, listen to them.

Comment: @Glorfindel If your statements are true then that's good news but at least someone who is an expert in this area could help me  confirming if i'm eligible for an EU residence card and how to apply for it  ? If not what are the other solutions that I could do?

Comment: @KevinDrizzy I only edited your question for better readability. I have no statements to make.

Comment: OP is over 21 (born in 1994) which likely doesn't help.

Answer (score 5):

If, as you say, your entire family lives in Germany, then it does not take any great leap of logic for a consular officer to assume that you would prefer to stay with them rather than return to Algeria.  As an applicant for a stort-stay visa, it is *your* task to provide evidence that *refutes* that assumption.

It doesn't sound like it will be easily possible for a student to refute that assumption.  Having a significantly well-paid job in Algeria would probably suffice; having a family there who depend on you *and* a stable job that allows you to provide for them without going abroad probably would too.  As a student, though, you're probably out of luck.

---

But your description sounds strange. If your father is a German citizen and you're not, it must either be because you have lost German citizenship acquired at birth, or because your father achieved German citizenship by naturalization after you were born -- but in that case it is strange that you and your mother were not included in the naturalization (at least according to Wikipedia's description, spouses and minor children will usually be naturalized at the same time).

So there seems to be something unusual going on here, and you (or your family) should probably consult a German lawyer specializing in nationality/immigration issues to find out if there's something that needs fixing there.  In any case, it is probably not something random people on the Internet will be able to help you with.

Comment: Yes, my father had his German citisenship in 1994 and i was born in 1992 i'am truly out of luck, but as i can clarify from your answer if i do not get a well payed job and do not have stronger bondes in my country then i'am not able to visite my family!? That sounds a bit terrifying speciely when it comes to your immeadiate derivatives, but do you think a human right or a immigration lawyer could be the beat solution and what are my chances?

Answer (score 1):

Like Henning, I think you and your father should look into the citizenship question, but that requires a specialized lawyer.

In the meantime, perhaps your father qualifies for signing a [Verpflichtungserklärung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verpflichtungserkl%C3%A4rung_(Ausl%C3%A4nderrecht)). It is a promise to reimburse the German state for any costs if you overstay, intentionally or unintentionally. This requires a sufficient income to pay for you and for any other dependents he may have.

Comment: As long as my family still lives there granting me a visa would be difficult but at least I should be eligible for another type of visa because Schengen laws doesn't work in my favour,it must be something that has to be done maybe a qualified lawyer could help much.

Comment: @KevinDrizzy, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying here. I can see two **different** approaches, first looking into the family reunification angle, and second looking into the Verpflichtungserklärung. A Verpflichtungserklärung would help with an ordinary, non-family visa.